# Trying to get horizontal touchpad scrolling working in Sly library on a Mac

Tags: javascript, touchpad, sly-scroller

I am trying to get the Sly library to scroll the FRAME div just from the trackpad of a Macbook Pro. To be clear, I am specifically looking for scrolling the items in my frame (inside the `.slidee` element) using the two finger gesture -- I am not interested in click-and-drag.

I have the following:

```
<div id="frame" class="frame">
  <ul class="slidee">
    <li>dkfsjdsakjf</li>
    <!-- ... other items -->
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="scrollbar-container">
  <div id="scrollbar" class="scrollbar">
    <div class="handle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    var options = {
      horizontal: 1,
      itemNav: 'basic',
      scrollBar: '#scrollbar',
      dragHandle: true,
      speed: 300,
      mouseDragging: 1,
      touchDragging: 1
    };
    $('#frame').sly(options);
</script>
```

The SCSS for these is here:

```
.frame { width: 100%; height: 160px; padding: 0; }
.frame .slidee { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; list-style: none; }
.frame .slidee li { float: left; margin: 0 5px 0 0; padding: 0; width: 120px; height: 100%; }

.scrollbar { width: 100%; height: 30px; }
.scrollbar .handle {
  width: 100px; /* overriden if dynamicHandle: 1 */
  height: 100%;
  background: #222;
  border-radius: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scrollbar-container {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  opacity: .5;
  bottom: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: inherit;
}
```

However, I am not able to horizontally scroll the `#frame` nor am I sure if that is a supported feature. Any help is greatly appreciated!